# RECORD_START|STOP event in Freeswitch ESL

Tags: freeswitch

I have setup a NodeJS application (with node_esl) and connected it with event socket layer (ESL) of a Freeswitch server deployed on Amazon AWS. See code below:

```
var esl = require('modesl'),
conn = new esl.Connection('SERVER_IP', PORT, 'PASSWORD', function() {
        conn.api('status', function(res) {
            //res is an esl.Event instance
            console.log(res.getBody());
        });


    conn.subscribe([
        'RECORD_START',
        'RECORD_STOP'
    ], function(evt) {
        console.log(evt)    
    });

    conn.on('esl::event::RECORD_START::*', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });

    conn.on('esl::event::RECORD_STOP::*', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });
});
```

I am recording a video conference in Freeswitch using following commands and I expect the above interface to receive the RECORD_START|STOP events. However the said events are never received.

```
# To start recording
conference <conf_id> recording start
# To stop recording
conference <conf_id> recording stop
```

Below is Freeswitch profile for the conference I am recording:

```
<profile name="cp">
  <param name="domain" value="$${domain}"/>
  <param name="rate" value="8000"/>
  <param name="video-mode" value="transcode"/>
  <param name="interval" value="20"/>
  <param name="caller-controls" value="default"/>
  <param name="energy-level" value="0"/>
  <param name="conference-flags" value="wait-mod|audio-always|livearray-sync|livearray-json-status"/>
  <param name="max-members" value="25"/>
  <param name="sound-prefix" value="/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/sounds/"/>
  <param name="enter-sound" value="tone_stream://%(200,0,500,600,700)"/>
  <param name="exit-sound" value="tone_stream://%(500,0,300,200,100,50,25)"/>
</profile>
```

I receive majority of ESL events through this interface but not the RECORD_START|STOP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out and it looks like the RECORD_START|STOP events only emit for the [record](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools:+record) application (and probably the [record_session](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools:+record_session) application. I did not test this), but not for conference recording.

For troubleshooting, I ran `fs_cli> /event plain all` from the freeswitch command line, and these events did show up when I ran `conference <conf_id> recording start` and `conference <conf_id> recording stop`.

Here is the start event:

```
RECV EVENT
Event-Subclass: conference::maintenance
Event-Name: CUSTOM
Core-UUID: fe0ebcc0-0c43-44ed-adb3-ce4e7ee8f48b
FreeSWITCH-Hostname: freeswitch
FreeSWITCH-Switchname: freeswitch
FreeSWITCH-IPv4: 192.168.1.114
FreeSWITCH-IPv6: ::1
Event-Date-Local: 2017-09-14 17:38:22
Event-Date-GMT: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 17:38:22 GMT
Event-Date-Timestamp: 1505410702748201
Event-Calling-File: conference_record.c
Event-Calling-Function: conference_record_thread_run
Event-Calling-Line-Number: 278
Event-Sequence: 990
Conference-Name: conference
Conference-Size: 1
Conference-Ghosts: 0
Conference-Profile-Name: cp
Conference-Unique-ID: a431361f-a59b-4319-bec1-fa76f8630197
Action: start-recording
Path:{channels=1,samplerate=8000,vw=0,vh=0,fps=0.00}/usr/local/freeswitch/log/conference_recording_1.mp3
Error: File could not be opened for recording
```

Here is the stop event:

```
RECV EVENT
Event-Subclass: conference::maintenance
Event-Name: CUSTOM
Core-UUID: fe0ebcc0-0c43-44ed-adb3-ce4e7ee8f48b
FreeSWITCH-Hostname: freeswitch
FreeSWITCH-Switchname: freeswitch
FreeSWITCH-IPv4: 192.168.1.114
FreeSWITCH-IPv6: ::1
Event-Date-Local: 2017-09-14 17:38:22
Event-Date-GMT: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 17:38:22 GMT
Event-Date-Timestamp: 1505410702748201
Event-Calling-File: conference_record.c
Event-Calling-Function: conference_record_thread_run
Event-Calling-Line-Number: 418
Event-Sequence: 991
Conference-Name: conference
Conference-Size: 1
Conference-Ghosts: 0
Conference-Profile-Name: cp
Conference-Unique-ID: a431361f-a59b-4319-bec1-fa76f8630197
Action: stop-recording
Path: {channels=1,samplerate=8000,vw=0,vh=0,fps=0.00}/usr/local/freeswitch/log/conference_recording_1.mp3
Other-Recordings: true
Samples-Out: 0
Samplerate: 8000
Milliseconds-Elapsed: 0
```

For your node app, you could try something like this to get what you need:

```js
var esl = require('modesl'),

conn = new esl.Connection('127.0.0.1', 8021, 'ClueCon', function() {
  conn.api('status', function(res) {
    //res is an esl.Event instance
    console.log(res.getBody());
  });

  conn.subscribe('CUSTOM conference::maintenance', function() {
    conn.on('esl::event::CUSTOM::**', function(evt) {
       console.log(evt);
       // now do something
    });
  });
});
```